# .NET Core 2.2, publishing all DLLs to ref folder from AspNetCore.App package

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core, refs, .net-core-2.2

I have recently migrated from .NET Core v1.1 to v2.2. Part of this migration included removing 8 or 9 Microsoft.AspNetCore nuget packages and replacing them with the almighty Microsoft.AspNetCore.App package.

My understanding of using this was that the unused DLLs would essentially be shaken out of the app when it's published. I have also been reading about the runtime store and can see that it's fully populated.

So, when I publish my app to a file, why do I now have 337 DLLs in my ref folder when I previously had 118. I can only presume these are all the DLLs from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App package? Have I missed a setting in the config to remove them? I don't want them there, it triples the size of the refs folder!

If there's something I need to change, could you please explain what it is? If I have misunderstood something, please correct me.

Edit: I am not publishing as self contained.